# Retrieve specific field based on structure of file, awk

Tags: awk

MyFile:

```
    1       Cufflinks       exon    162752  163607  .       +       .       gene_id "XLOC_000001"; transcript_id "TCONS_00000001"; exon_number "1"; oId "CUFF.1.1"; class_code "u"; tss_id "TSS1";
    1       Cufflinks       exon    177199  177399  .       +       .       gene_id "XLOC_000002"; transcript_id "TCONS_00000002"; exon_number "1"; oId "CUFF.3.1"; class_code "u"; tss_id "TSS2";
    1       Cufflinks       exon    178775  179390  .       +       .       gene_id "XLOC_000003"; transcript_id "TCONS_00000003"; exon_number "1"; gene_name "ENSORLG00000000007"; oId "CUFF.15.1"; nearest_ref "ENSORLT00000000006"; class_code "s"; tss_id "TSS3";
    1       Cufflinks       exon    218671  219224  .       +       .       gene_id "XLOC_000007"; transcript_id "TCONS_00000005"; exon_number "1"; gene_name "slc43a1b"; oId "CUFF.50.1"; nearest_ref "ENSORLT00000000013"; class_code "s"; tss_id "TSS7";
```

Disired output:

```
    1       Cufflinks       exon    162752  163607  .       +       .       gene_id "XLOC_000001"; transcript_id "TCONS_00000001"; exon_number "1"; oId "CUFF.1.1"; class_code "u"; tss_id "TSS1";
    1       Cufflinks       exon    177199  177399  .       +       .       gene_id "XLOC_000002"; transcript_id "TCONS_00000002"; exon_number "1"; oId "CUFF.3.1"; class_code "u"; tss_id "TSS2";
    1       Cufflinks       exon    180630  180720  .       +       .       gene_id "XLOC_000003"; transcript_id "ENSORLT00000000006"; exon_number "5"; gene_name "ENSORLG00000000007"; oId "CUFF.15.1"; nearest_ref "ENSORLT00000000006"; class_code "s"; tss_id "TSS3";
    1       Cufflinks       exon    218671  219224  .       +       .       gene_id "XLOC_000007"; transcript_id "ENSORLT00000000013"; exon_number "1"; gene_name "slc43a1b"; oId "CUFF.50.1"; nearest_ref "ENSORLT00000000013"; class_code "s"; tss_id "TSS7";
```

Explanation:

If there is a field `nearest_ref`, write it in field `transcript_id`, else, do nothing.

Field `nearest_ref`:

```
nearest_ref "XXXXXXX";
```

Field `transcript_id`:

```
transcript_id "XXXXXXX";
```

I would like a `awk` solution if possible.

I don't know how to retrive fields based on their name and not on their position :

```
awk -v FS=" " 'length($20)>20{$12=$20} 1' MyFile |less
```

*Note : File is tab separated, 9th column is space separated.*

***Edit: Found a way to do it, but it is really bad, I am still interested in a better way to do it:***

```
awk -v FS=" " -v OFS="\t" 'length($20)>20{$12=$20} 1' MyFile | sed "s/;\t/; /g" | sed 's/\t"/ "/g'
```

Comment: Just edited my post

Comment: what does it have to do with lenght > 20?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you have name->value pairs, I find it's clearest and easiest to modify in future to first create an array to hold that mapping (n2v[] below) and then just modify the array using the names as indices:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS="\t"
    src = "nearest_ref"
    dst = "transcript_id"
}
{
    n = split($9,f," ")
    delete n2v
    for (i=1; i<=n; i+=2) {
        name  = f[i]
        value = f[i+1]
        n2v[name] = value
    }

    new = ""
    for (i=1; i<=n; i+=2) {
        name  = f[i]
        value = ((name == dst) && (src in n2v) ? n2v[src] : n2v[name])
        new = (i>1 ? new " " : "") name " " value
    }
    $9 = new

    print
}
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file
1       Cufflinks       exon    162752  163607  .       +       .       gene_id "XLOC_000001"; transcript_id "TCONS_00000001"; exon_number "1"; oId "CUFF.1.1"; class_code "u"; tss_id "TSS1";
1       Cufflinks       exon    177199  177399  .       +       .       gene_id "XLOC_000002"; transcript_id "TCONS_00000002"; exon_number "1"; oId "CUFF.3.1"; class_code "u"; tss_id "TSS2";
1       Cufflinks       exon    178775  179390  .       +       .       gene_id "XLOC_000003"; transcript_id "ENSORLT00000000006"; exon_number "1"; gene_name "ENSORLG00000000007"; oId "CUFF.15.1"; nearest_ref "ENSORLT00000000006"; class_code "s"; tss_id "TSS3";
1       Cufflinks       exon    218671  219224  .       +       .       gene_id "XLOC_000007"; transcript_id "ENSORLT00000000013"; exon_number "1"; gene_name "slc43a1b"; oId "CUFF.50.1"; nearest_ref "ENSORLT00000000013"; class_code "s"; tss_id "TSS7";
```

With that you can swap whatever other fields you like, change the order they're output in or do whatever else you like just by accessing the values by their names.

Comment: If I understand I can write for example: `print n2v["transcript_id"]` instead of `print` to get my transcript id in each line ?

Comment: Yes, just try it.

Answer (score 2):

simple enough for `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/(transcript_id )[^;]+(.*nearest_ref )([^;]+);/\1\3\2\3;/' file
```

output

```
    1       Cufflinks       exon    162752  163607  .       +       .       gene_id "XLOC_000001"; transcript_id "TCONS_00000001"; exon_number "1"; oId "CUFF.1.1"; class_code "u"; tss_id "TSS1";
    1       Cufflinks       exon    177199  177399  .       +       .       gene_id "XLOC_000002"; transcript_id "TCONS_00000002"; exon_number "1"; oId "CUFF.3.1"; class_code "u"; tss_id "TSS2";
    1       Cufflinks       exon    178775  179390  .       +       .       gene_id "XLOC_000003"; transcript_id "ENSORLT00000000006"; exon_number "1"; gene_name "ENSORLG00000000007"; oId "CUFF.15.1"; nearest_ref "ENSORLT00000000006"; class_code "s"; tss_id "TSS3";
    1       Cufflinks       exon    218671  219224  .       +       .       gene_id "XLOC_000007"; transcript_id "ENSORLT00000000013"; exon_number "1"; gene_name "slc43a1b"; oId "CUFF.50.1"; nearest_ref "ENSORLT00000000013"; class_code "s"; tss_id "TSS7";
```